# Проблема с  array_key_exists()

Tags: php

Вот что говорит сервер

> Warning: array_key_exists() expects
> parameter 2 to be array, string given
> in
> /home/www-data/www/test/core/classes/autoloader.class.php
> on line 28

На 28 строке находится условие

```
if(!empty(self::$_classMap) && array_key_exists($class, self::$_classMap[$class])){                      
  require self::$_classMap[$class];           
  return true;
}
```

Comment: По этому участку кода мало что понятно, но кажется, что подстроку

    array_key_exists($class, self::$_classMap[$class])

нужно заменить на 

    array_key_exists($class, self::$_classMap)

Comment: @Алексей Скляр, вот именно потому, что второй параметр и должен быть массивом, а не строкой.